# Xcode: Adding a Test that fails when there are Static Analyzer warnings or errors?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, clang-static-analyzer

I want my Xcode project's tests to fail when there are analyzer warnings or errors.

Running the Xcode "Analyze" command points out the analyzer errors in your project:

[image: Static Analyzer error]

However, when I use Xcode's "Test" command on this same target I'm all green:

[image: Passing tests]

Is there a way to add a "Run Static Analyzer" test or build phase to the testing target? We are using `XCTest`. I find myself sometimes testing the target and thinking things are fine, only to have forgotten to fix a simple memory issue.

Our tests should fail when there are analyzer warnings or errors.

Comment: Why aren't you using ARC?

Comment: It's an older project that hasn't yet been converted to ARC, but that's beside the point; even under ARC the analyzer would complain about improper Core Foundation MRR and other errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can set it to analyze during build in the build settings (just search for analyze). Set "Analyze during 'Build'" to YES.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. I'd still like to see if there's a way to analyze only during tests, for faster normal builds.

Comment: For that I would just create a separate Test configuration and set "Analyze during 'Build'" = YES for that configuration only.